# Unsupported class file major version

Tags: java, gradle, compatibility, dafny

I'm having an error when trying to compile Dafny from source. If I try to do it I get the following output:

```
$ make exe
(cd /home/xbreu/Documents/University/SpecRep/dafny/ ; dotnet build Source/Dafny.sln ) includes parser
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.1+b177f8fa7 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Compiling DafnyRuntimeJava to DafnyRuntimeJava/build/libs/DafnyRuntime.jar...

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * Where:
  Settings file '/home/xbreu/Documents/University/SpecRep/dafny/Source/DafnyRuntime/DafnyRuntimeJava/settings.gradle'

  * What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file '/home/xbreu/Documents/University/SpecRep/dafny/Source/DafnyRuntime/DafnyRuntimeJava/settings.gradle'.
  > startup failed:
    General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.TypeSignatureParser.visitEnd(TypeSignatureParser.java:110)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.signature.SignatureReader.parseType(SignatureReader.java:206)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.signature.SignatureReader.accept(SignatureReader.java:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.ClassSignatureParser.parseClassSignature(ClassSignatureParser.java:74)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.ClassSignatureParser.configureClass(ClassSignatureParser.java:32)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitSupers(DecompiledClassNode.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.isUsingGenerics(DecompiledClassNode.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.nonGeneric(GenericsUtils.java:275)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:101)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lambda$createMethodNode$1(DecompiledClassNode.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode(DecompiledClassNode.java:236)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:203)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.tryFindPossibleMethod(ClassNode.java:1283)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:138)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1089)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.lambda$addPhaseOperations$3(CompilationUnit.java:209)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:942)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:671)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:635)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:190)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:170)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:211)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:194)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:86)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:216)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:206)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:139)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:89)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:43)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:103)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:117)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:125)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:136)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.initialization.GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.java:39)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:45)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareSettings$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:226)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$10(StateTransitionController.java:201)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:197)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$2(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:226)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransition$9(StateTransitionController.java:187)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransition(StateTransitionController.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:132)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:89)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

    1 error


  * Try:
  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 2s
/home/xbreu/Documents/University/SpecRep/dafny/Source/DafnyRuntime/DafnyRuntime.csproj(47,5): error MSB3073: The command "./gradlew -q build" exited with code 1.
```

It looks like a compatibility issue, because of the "Unsupported class file major version 63", so I must have some program that is not compatible with major version 63 (which corresponds to Java 19). But the versions of Java, Gradle and .NET look compatible:

Java:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7, mixed mode)
```

Gradle:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-03-03 20:07:03 UTC
Revision:     <unknown>

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          19.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 19.0.2+7)
OS:           Linux 6.2.2-arch1-1 amd64
```

.NET:

```
$ dotnet --version
6.0.114
```

I tried cloning the repository again and reinstalling the programs, and nothing has helped me so far. What problem could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Dafny use Gradle 7.4, which does not support yet JDK 19 but up to JDK 17.
Since you are modifying from source, feel free to update the Gradle version and create a PR, or you can downgrade the JDK version.

Comment: Oh, that small thing was it, I found where the gradle configuration from Dafny was and changed it. Thanks, I don't know how I have not verified that.